# Angular NPM weird dependency conflict error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies, node-modules

I have a weird issue with npm. I deleted node modules, deleted package-lock.json,run npm cache clean --force, but when I do npm install I get the following error -

```
    Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.7" from @angular/localize@14.2.7
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
    npm ERR!   @angular/localize@"^14.2.7" from the root project

package.json

    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/common": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/localize": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/material": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.1",
        "@angular/router": "14.2.1",
```

I don't understand why I get this error. It looks like npm still has something cached? Why is there a conflict between 2 packages of the same version?

Comment: `npm install @angular/localize@14.2.1`

Comment: try `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@angular/localize@14.2.1 not 14.2.7`

generally speaking

the package version of each module of angular is the same